# Handle App widget's update() method from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I did a sample from [App Widget Article](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html), Where I used Service for update the App widget.

Now I want to programatically update the App Widget from custom interval (run time interval).

***How can I do this?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example how to set create an update event for AppWidget. You can customize it for your purposes:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(ExampleAppWidgetProvider.MY_INTENT_ACTION);
Uri data = Uri.withAppendedPath (Uri.parse("wordwidget://wordwidget/widgetId/#"),
                String.valueOf(mAppWidgetId));
intent.setData(data);
intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, mAppWidgetId);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.this, 0, intent,
PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 10*1000, pendingIntent);
```

You should also make an additional intent-filter for your BR that will receive the intent with action name: `ExampleAppWidgetProvider.MY_INTENT_ACTION`

**UPDATE**
To your Broadcast Receiver you should add new intent-filter like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="org.android.testwidget.MY_APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    <data android:scheme="wordwidget" />
</intent-filter>
```

Then you create an Intent that will be received by the defined intent-filter. In my case,  `public static final String MY_INTENT_ACTION = "org.android.testwidget.MY_APPWIDGET_UPDATE";`
Data part of the Intent is needed to create a separate intent for each AppWidget instance (because I want to update each instance in different time). After that you create Pending intent for BR and create alarmManager with this PI. In the method `setRepeating` you define the start time and the interval for your AppWidget instance.

Comment: Can you explain a little more please?